# Is that possible to show info about class which is currently editing?

Tags: eclipse

In intelliJ IDEA I can always see what class I'm working on because of clear path to this class shown in the top bar. Is there a possibility to have something like that in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can turn on "breadcrumbs" in the Java editor. I can never remember the key binding, but there's a button for it on the default toolbar.

Alternatively, you can have either the Project Explorer or the Package Explorer (depending on which you prefer/use) link with the editor so that the currently edited file is always shown in those views. It's the button on the view toolbar with the two yellow arrows.